# Swift. How to use concurrency with viewDidLoad() without Task

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor, swift-concurrency

It can be strange question, but in my understanding `UIViewController` is `@MainActor`, so if I want to start concurrency code from `override func viewDidLoad`, I don't need to write `Task {}`. But now it needed. Is there any way to use concurrency from `UIViewController` without writing `Task {`?

Example:

```swift
let interactor: InteractorInterace

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupUI()

    // Already main actor

    Task { // <- why we need it?
        let request = TestModels.DidLoad.Request()
        await interactor?.viewDidLoad(request: request)
    }
}

protocol InteractorInterface {
    func viewDidLoad(request: TestModels.DidLoad.Request) async
}

actor Interactor: InteractorInterface { ... }
```

Comment: We need more details about the interactor and the method. Is it isolated to a custom actor? Is `viewDidLoad(request:)` an `async` method?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the view controller would need to use `Task {…}` to invoke an `async` method from another method that is either (a) `async` or (b) isolated to a different actor.

So, is the interactor’s `viewDidLoad(request:)` actually an `async` method? In so, then, yes, `Task {…}` is needed. In this scenario, the fact that the view controller is isolated to the main actor is irrelevant. It’s just a matter of getting to an `async` context.

But is it just a synchronous method isolated to a different actor? If so, you could consider isolating the interactor to the main actor, instead, in which case the view controller would no longer need to use `Task {…}`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown what `interactor` is, but I'll assume it is either an actor that is not `@MainActor`, or `viewDidLoad(request:)` is itself an async method. In either case, you would have to `await` the call, as you are.

You must be in an asynchronous context in order to `await`. `viewDidLoad()` is not an async method, so it does not create an async context. It has nothing to do with the class or `@MainActor`. The method itself must be marked `async` (you can't do that here, since the superclass implementation is not async).

So you need to create an async context, and the common way to do that is with Task.

Another way to say this is that the caller of `viewDidLoad` is promised that the method will not suspend. If it could suspend, then it would be marked `async`. `viewDidLoad` must return without calling `await`. So you must move that `await` into a separate Task, and return immediately.